# Replacing PHP associative array value (string) with an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, for-loop, associative-array

I'd like to replace the 'baz' values in the 'BLOCKS' array with the arrays within the 'BAZ' array whose titles match.

I've tried exploding BLOCKS['baz'], then looping through the result and doing a str_replace to no avail. I'm sure there's a more succinct and direct solution.

See DESIRED OUTPUT at the bottom for what I'm trying to accomplish. Many thanks!

```
    BLOCKS

    array
      0 => 
        array
          'foo' => string 'block1' (length=6)
          'bar' => string '/uploads/commercial/pdf.pdf' (length=27)
          'baz' => string '372|371' (length=7)
      1 => 
        array
          'foo' => string 'block2' (length=6)
          'bar' => string '/uploads/commercial/pdf.pdf' (length=27)
          'baz' => string '371' (length=3)

    BAZ

    array
      372 => 
        array
          'wibble' => string 'building2' (length=9)
          'wobble' => int 235000
          'wubble' => string 'office|medical' (length=14)
      371 => 
        array
          'wibble' => string 'building1' (length=9)
          'wobble' => int 252000
          'wubble' => string 'office' (length=6)

    DESIRED OUTPUT

    array
      0 => 
        array
          'foo' => 'block1'
          'bar' => '/uploads/commercial/pdf.pdf'
          'baz' => array(
            372 => 
              array
                'wibble' => string 'building2' (length=9)
                'wobble' => int 235000
                'wubble' => string 'office|medical' (length=14)
            371 => 
              array
                'wibble' => string 'building1' (length=9)
                'wobble' => int 252000
                'wubble' => string 'office' (length=6)
            );

      1 => 
        array
          'foo' => string 'block2' (length=6)
          'bar' => string '/uploads/commercial/pdf.pdf' (length=27)
          'baz' => array(
            371 => 
              array
                'wibble' => string 'building1' (length=9)
                'wobble' => int 252000
                'wubble' => string 'office' (length=6)
            )              
          );
```

Comment: Please add the code what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($blocks as &$block) {

    $bazIds = explode('|', $block['baz']);

    unset($block['baz']); // Keep it clean

    foreach ($bazIds as $bazId) {

        if (array_key_exists($bazId, $baz) {
            $block['baz'][$bazId] = $baz[$bazId];
        }
    } 
}
```